# vb.net select listviewitem by giving it's index

Tags: vb.net, listview, selectlistitem

I'm searching everywhere but I cannot seem to find the answer.

In VB.net I want to select a listviewitem by giving it's index.

Let say: If I push a button it has to select row 5.

I don't seem to get it to work...

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: ListView for? ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF ....

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume the following situation:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListView1.Items.Add("Item 1") 'Index 0
    ListView1.Items.Add("Item 2") 'Index 1
    ListView1.Items.Add("Item 3") 'Index 2
End Sub
```

You can select an item by using:

```
    ListView1.Items.Item(index).Selected = True
```

For example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListView1.Items.Item(1).Selected = True

    'Not necessary, just to show the blue color instead of gray
    ListView1.Select()
End Sub
```

Here is the result before and after pressing `Button1`.

[image: Before]
[image: After]